# MVC6 FileNotFoundException: System.Data.SqlClient

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, filenotfoundexception, asp.net-core-mvc, sqlclient

Good day,

Why Am I getting this error with my MVC6 project? I already added System.Data.SqlClient 4.0.0-beta-23019 nuget package in my project.json. Any suggestions?

Error message:

FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably due to version conflicts in assemblies, Microsoft have developed a tool named Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 (Beta6) – Visual Studio 2015 to resolve the best suited versions for current assemblies. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48222

Better use this and start your project. But is you still wants to stick with the project your project.json should look something like this.

```
"dependencies": {
    "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-23109",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-23109",
    "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-23109",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.10-beta-23109",
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-23109"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
      },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Data": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the version you were probably looking for is `4.0.0-beta-23109`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I am using **4.0.0-beta-23109**.